# What is the meaning of "unknown.unknown" in Network Domain in Google Analytics? How does it differ from "(not set)""?

Tags: google-analytics

We've noticed in the Network Domain column the value "unknown.unknown"

My understanding is that the information in this column is generated by Google Analytics using a DNS reverse lookup.

When a reverse lookup fails - the value "(not set)" is applied.

It is unclear to me as to how "unknown.unknown" differs from "not set"?

I've checked for such a domain (dig unknown.unknown, whois unknown.unknown) and no answer is returned.

Comment: It has been a very long time since I looked into this, however, they are just two different responses based upon what the DNS has returned. I do not remember the details. Sorry. I would not worry about it. Cheers!!